# F# Three Arrays - Replace Unique Values In Original Array With New Values

Tags: arrays, replace, f#, match, unique

I have three arrays - first, second, and third. second comprises the unique values of first and third contains the new values for replacement in first by mapping to second, as follows:

```
module SOQN = 

   open System

   let first  = [|"A"; "B"; "C"; "A"; "B"; "A"; "C"; "B"; "C"; "C"; "C"|]
   let second = [|"A"; "B"; "C"|]
   let third  = [|"1"; "2"; "3"|]

   let rplc (x:string[]) (y:string[]) (z:string[]) = 
      first
      // |> Array.map (fun w -> Array.iter2 (fun x y -> (if w = x then y)) second third)

   let fourth = 
      rplc first second third

   printfn ""
   printfn "fourth: %A" fourth

   // Expected Result: fourth: [|"1"; "2"; "3"; "1"; "2"; "1"; "3"; "2"; "3"; "3"; "3"|]
   // Actual Result:   fourth: [|"A"; "B"; "C"; "A"; "B"; "A"; "C"; "B"; "C"; "C"; "C"|]
```

My commented line fails but I am not sure why?

Comment: You should create a dictionary/map from the second and third list, then use the first list as a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to create a lookup table from the second and third arrays, than map over each element of the first array, and use it as a key.

```
let first  = [|"A"; "B"; "C"; "A"; "B"; "A"; "C"; "B"; "C"; "C"; "C"|]
let second = [|"A"; "B"; "C"|]
let third  = [|"1"; "2"; "3"|]

let lookupTbl = Map(Array.zip second third) //create a Map/Dictionary from the zipped values

first
|> Array.map (fun x -> lookupTbl.[x]) //Use the first array's values as keys
//val it : string [] = [|"1"; "2"; "3"; "1"; "2"; "1"; "3"; "2"; "3"; "3"; "3"|]
```

You can also use `TryFind` if you are not sure all keys exist, but that doesn't seem necessary in your case.

Your original case doesn't work because you are trying to use `if` as a statement, so it returns `unit` (because what happens if x is not equal to w).

If you want to stay closer to your original structure, you can pattern match instead of the if, then remove the non-matches. `Array.collect` collapses the array of arrays into one array. The `match` expression does what the `if` in your code, but it return `Some` value if there's a match, and `None` otherwise. Finally we get rid of the `None` and `Some` Option wrappers with `Array.choose`.

```
let rplc (x:string[]) (y:string[]) (z:string[]) = 
  first
  |> Array.collect (fun w -> 
                        Array.map2 (fun x y -> 
                                                match (w = x) with
                                                | true -> Some(y)
                                                | _ -> None ) second third)
  |> Array.choose id

let fourth = 
  rplc first second third

printfn ""
printfn "fourth: %A" fourth

// val fourth : string [] =
//   [|"1"; "2"; "3"; "1"; "2"; "1"; "3"; "2"; "3"; "3"; "3"|]
// val it : unit = ()
```